# Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]' Even I use ES7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, package, ecmascript-2016

I found this issue on other page, as people said I should change the lib in tsconfig.josn, but after I have changed compile to es7, it still pop up the same error and couldn't be packed and build.

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: try `es7` instead? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11890 Would think they would be the same, but you never know. Additionally someone says set the target to es2016 but that seems like a terrible idea unless you only want to support the latest versions of edge, chrome, and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it can't work is because we use ng-packagr to package part of code, and it didn't pick up the tsconfig.json lib.

The solution for my issue is, added languageLevel into ng-package.json, it should override the traget: "es5", and able to build es7 file.

```js
{
  "ngPackage": {
    "lib": {
      "languageLevel": ["dom", "es2017"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do the same change i.e

```
 "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
```

in the **tsconfig.lib.json**. of your library project.

There by default it is 2015